# Why Clamtk is not scanning anything?

Tags: antivirus, clamtk

I am new to *Ubuntu* had installed *ClamTK* antivirus using command:

```
sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk
```

and i am unable to scan anything. Whenever i try to scan it completes within 1 second and I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

which shows 0 files scanned,but i selected a directory and scanned it.Where is the problem?I had also tried updating *Clamtk* using command
`sudo freshclam`
but it shows this error

```
ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Does the directory actually contain any files? Is at least one of them not excluded from the virus search (e. g. by file extension)?

Answer (score 3):

> The clamtk settings may not be selected correctly. By default, some settings may be disabled and you may have to activate them as below.
>   Please check *Configuration* -> *Settings* menu for the items below and activate them by ticking/selecting;
>
> - tick -> scan files larger than 20 MB
> - tick -> scan directories recursively

Answer (score 0):

The ClamAV configuration file is probably still the default bundled with the the installation. To fix this error you have to:

1. Rename `/usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf.sample` to `freshclam.conf` and edit the line with the word `Example` to `#Example`.
   AND
2. Rename `/usr/local/etc/clamd.conf.sample` to `clamd.conf` and edit the line with the word `Example` to `#Example`.

Root owns these files so I did this using sudo from a terminal window:

```
 cd /usr/local/etc
 sudo cp freshclam.conf.sample freshclam.conf
 sudo cp clamd.conf.sample clamd.conf
 sudo gedit
```

Edit both `freshclam.conf` and `clamd.conf` and change line 8:
`Example` to `#Example`. Save the files.

You can get more elaborate by changing other lines in the files, but I don't want to go there.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the `freshclam.conf.sample` and `clamd.conf.sample` files (removing the `.sample`), as well es editing them in a text editor and adding an `#` in front of line 8 (which is "Example"), and then to enable the in-terminal scan feature, run:

```
sudo freshclam
```

Next, run (where `%directory%` is the path you want to scan):

```
clamscan %directory%
```

As well as the `clamtk` app scanning feature.

I'm flabbergasted by how hard this solution was to find. It's such a common error.

Answer (score -1):

Also, remove spaces from file names. It clamtk probably thinks you want several files scanned and can't find them. For example text_file.txt will be scanned text file.txt will not be scanned because it thinks you want to scan a file named text and a file named file. Linux in general doesn't like spaces in file names. Any function in terminal on a file with spaces in terminal should have " " around file name i.e. clamscan "text file.txt"

Answer (score -1):

I only got the Clamtk GUI to work after I typed:
clamscan -r --remove /
in the terminal to use the terminal to scan for viruses.  After doing that
the GUI now works.  Hope this helps.